# Using CSS in Blazor to print pages in Landscape and Portrait

Tags: css, blazor

I am currently working on a project where the user can print invoices. I am using Blazor as my framework. I want to print some invoices in portrait and others in landscape. I am currently using

@media print{
@page{
size: landscape;  (or size: portrait)
}
}

The issue is that even though I have these on a per razor component css file, they seem to overwrite each other.

I have tried using transform: rotate but if there are multiple pages to the invoice, it does not properly page break and it renders completely wrong.

Comment: Can you show an example please ?
I dont quite understand your problem.

Comment: Its hard to really show. Basically, If I use size: landscape for one page, it applies to all the other pages, which is something I dont want to happen. I need a way to isolate the @media print query to a single razor component.

Comment: You can try adding it inline to the specific component you want.

`<div style="size: landscape;">` For example